# Browser style tabs on the windows navigation bar

Tags: electron

I am designing a electron app that is geared to look like a browser (i.e., google chrome), with tabs on the navigation bar.

I want to keep the windows style buttons in the top right for closing, maximizing and minimizing and the border with Windows color.

Currently I am using a frameless electron window and attempting to replicate the Windows 10 GUI but I am coming into a few roadblocks.

1. How do I get the window color?
2. When un-focused Windows 10 gives a window a 1px transparent grey border. Any transparent border I create is overlayed against electron's window background and is not transparent.
3. Where can I find the windows resources to replicate the top right window buttons? I want this to look like windows, not a custom GUI.

Then come the difficulties of replicating this approach for something like the Aero Glass style of Windows 7. Is there a better way to do this? Say perhaps draw directly onto the window border in a way I am not aware of, or is this the only approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to get this information via a native module that accesses the `winAPI`. There are packages that will help you if your not familiar with writing the binding yourselfe.

   - https://www.npmjs.com/package/winapi
   - https://www.npmjs.com/package/win32api
2. You can make the window transperent and then add a margin to the html/body instead of using a border when unfocused. check the electron [docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/frameless-window.md#transparent-window) for how to make the window transperent.
3. You will need to consider the diffrences in DPI Windows7 / Windows 10 and also any further change on the windows 10 lifetime, they will definitly change the appearance over the years. Otherwise you could extract the SVG's and styling from here https://codepen.io/agrimsrud/pen/WGgRPP MS did not publish the files so there is no way to get the original ones.

If you want native windows you should not make the window frameless, i think adding the tab support for windows which actually exists should be added to electron. Maybe create a Issue on GitHub, i think the devs there can give you some better hints on how to archive what you want.